# HttpClient changes HTTPS to HTTP on some machines

Tags: c#, .net, dotnet-httpclient

I'm using HttpClient.PostAsync on a URL with an **HTTPS scheme**. The weird thing is that on one of my machines the request comes out as **plain HTTP**.

```
        var networkCredential = new NetworkCredential(_args.Username,_args.Password);
        var handler = new HttpClientHandler { Credentials = networkCredential };

        using (var client = new HttpClient(handler))
        {
                   var requestResult = client.PostAsync("https://www.example.com", new StringContent("")).Result.StatusCode;  
        }
```

I'm using Fiddler to sniff out what is actually sent. The bad machine runs dot net <strike>4.5.2</strike> 4.5 on Windows server 2008, however I've tested the code on another machine with  <strike>the same configuration</strike>, and everything worked fine.

Running said request on the bad machine outside of .net works fine.

Any ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I upgraded my .net framework to 4.6.2, and now everything works peachy.

As you can see, I originally thought the bad machine had .net 4.5.2, but it had actually had .net 4.5.